# Why can't I access the width of a THeaderSection

Tags: c++builder

I'm trying to use the width of a headersection in a THeaderControl in C++ Builder XE.
The THeaderControl is called "Header"
The TStringGrid I'm trying to align the widths with is called "Grid".
In the OnResize event handler for the Header, I've got the following code :

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::HeaderResize(TObject *Sender)
{
    for (int col=0; col<Header->Sections->Count; col++)
    {
        Grid->ColWidths[col]=Header->Sections[0].Width;
    }
}
```

which I thought would be OK, but it won't compile.

Can't seem to find out how to access the widths of the header.

Also, when i stuff something in here just to get it to compile (e.g. Grid->ColWidths[col]=100), the HeaderResize event handler doesn't get called (i.e. if I put a breakpoint in this loop, run the program and resize the header, it doesn't get to the breakpoint).

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: When you write "It won't compile", it helps greatly if you include the compiler error you're getting. We can't see your screen or the rest of your code from where we are, and you already have that information right in front of you.

Comment: Sorry, the code I've now got is as follows :

Comment: Sorry... The code I've now got here is:    void __fastcall TMainForm::HeaderResize(TObject *Sender)
{
 for (int col=0; col<Header->Sections->Count; col++)
  Grid->ColWidths[col]=Header->Sections[col].Width;
}  When I try and compile it I get the error [BCC32 Error] MainUnit.cpp(1695): E2316 'Width' is not a member of 'THeaderSections' (sorry about the formatting here, I'm having problems editing this comment. Don't know how to add a return)

Comment: `Sections[col]` does not do what you think it does. You are dereferencing a `THeaderSections` pointer, so the compiler treats it as a pointer to an array of `THeaderSections` object instances, which it is not. That is why the compiler complains that `Width` is not a member of `THeaderSections` - it is really not. You need to use the `Sections->Items[]` property to access individual `THeaderSection` objects instead.

Comment: With that said, why are you using a separate `THeaderControl` instead of letting the `TStringGrid` display its own header? If you set `TStringGrid::FixedRows` to 1, the first row will act like a header directly in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing the individual headers sections correctly.  You need to do it like this instead:

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::HeaderResize(TObject *Sender)
{
    for (int col=0; col<Header->Sections->Count; col++)
    {
        Grid->ColWidths[col] = Header->Sections->Items[col]->Width;
    }
}
```

Notice that `Sections[col]` is replaced with `Sections->Items[col]`, and that `.Width` is replaced with `->Width`.

As for the `OnResize` event not being triggered, `OnResize` is only triggered when the entire `THeaderControl` is resized.  When resizing individual sections, the `OnSectionResize` event is triggered instead.  That event tells you which section was resized, eg:

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::HeaderSectionResize(TCustomHeaderControl *HeaderControl, THeaderSection *Section)
{
    Grid->ColWidths[Section->Index] = Section->Width;
}
```